# how to stop the service after some time interval

Tags: android

I have restarted the service after every 5 minutes using AlarmManager's API. But I don't know how to stop this service after every 2 minutes(By giving some time interval).Is it possible to  stop the service after some time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code

This code will run after every 2 minutes

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       Intent parchment = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ServicesA.class);
       stopService(service);
    }
}, 120000);
```

Here 120000 milliseconds = 2 minutes

Comment: The problem here is that 2 minutes is too long-  if the phone goes to sleep in that period (relatively likely), this won't ever fire.  Handlers should be used for delays of milliseconds to seconds, not minutes.  Whereas an alarm will fire, because alarm events wake up the phone.

Answer (score 2):

You want to stop a service after a certain amount of time has passed?  Set up a one time alarm, and when the alarm fires call stopSelf().